# Python : Recursively flatten a list

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have a list `l = [2, 9, [1, 13], 8, 6]`. How can I flatten it recursively to get `l = [2, 9, 1, 13, 8, 6]`?

Comment: The dupe above not only has something that would probably answer you but there's a link to lots of questions in the question itself that have similar answers that might work as well.

Comment: The solutions there use methods which I've not yet come across as I've just started learning Python.

Comment: Before understanding my knowledge of Python, this thread was closed. I am a newbie in Python who learns Python whenever I get free from work. I shall raise the bar but it takes time guys. I could not understand the solution on the dupe or from the answer below. Anyway, I figured out the solution myself. If this thread opens up, I shall post my solution so that it can be optimized by experts here who didn't care to know about my knowledge of Python before closing this thread.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to flatten arbitrarily nested iterables, you could try this function:

```
def flatten(x):
    try:
        it = iter(x)
    except TypeError:
        yield x
    else:
        for i in it:
            for j in flatten(i):
                yield j
```

Example:

```
a = [2, 9, [1, 13], 8, 6]
list(flatten(a))
# [2, 9, 1, 13, 8, 6]
```

Note that the function would also flatten out strings to single characters.