# Python 2: insert existing list inside of new explicit list definition

Tags: python, list

This may not be possible, but if it is, it'd be convenient for some code I'm writing:

```
ListOne = ['jumps', 'over', 'the']
ListTwo = ['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', ListOne, 'lazy', 'dog!']
```

If I do this, I'll end up with ListOne being a single item being a list inside of ListTwo.

But instead, I want to expand ListOne into ListTwo, but I don't want to have to do something like:

```
ListOne = ['jumps', 'over', 'the']
ListTwo = ['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox']
ListTwo.extend(ListOne)
ListTwo.extend(['lazy', 'dog!']
```

This will work but it's not as readable as the above code.

Is this possible?

Comment: What you want to do is to flatten the list. That's been covered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409224/python-recursively-flatten-a-list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use the `+` operator to concatenate lists:

```
ListOne = ['jumps', 'over', 'the']
ListTwo = ['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox'] + ListOne + ['lazy', 'dog!']
```

`ListTwo` will be:

```
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog!']
```

Comment: Turned out to be the simplest way to get it to work. Thanks, I always forget about list concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use slicing assignment:

```
>>> ListOne = ['jumps', 'over', 'the']
>>> ListTwo = ['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'lazy', 'dog!']
>>> ListTwo[4:4] = ListOne
>>> ListTwo
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog!']
```

Comment: This avoids the temporary list that @grc's answer creates

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> ListOne = ['jumps', 'over', 'the']
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [x for x in chain(['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox'], ListOne, ['lazy', 'dog!'])]
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog!']
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not concatenate?

```
>>> ListTwo = ['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox']
>>> ListOne = ['jumps', 'over', 'the']
>>> ListTwo + ListOne
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the']
>>> ListTwo + ListOne + ['lazy', 'dog!']
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog!']
```